# regex ruby gsub: inserting space between characters in capture group

Tags: ruby, regex

I am trying to to convert strings like:

"foo(bar baz)bom" => "foo (bar baz) bom"

I have this so far:

```
"foo(bar baz)bom".gsub(/((\S\()|(\)\S))/,'\1')
```

But I am not sure what to do with the '\1' to insert a space between the parens and the character.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`"foo(bar baz)bom".gsub(/((?<! )\(|\)(?! ))/,"(" =>" (",")" =>") ")`

will do the trick.

Comment: There's a difference between matching non-space and not matching space, for example `"(x)" => " (x) "`

Answer (score 2):

Do as below

```
>> "foo(bar baz)bom".gsub(/[)(]/,"(" =>" (",")" =>") ")
=> "foo (bar baz) bom"
>>
```

**update**

```
>> "foo (bar baz)bom".gsub(/(?<=\S)\(|\)(?=\S)/,"(" =>" (",")" =>") ")
=> "foo (bar baz) bom"
>> "foo(bar baz)bom".gsub(/(?<=\S)\(|\)(?=\S)/,"(" =>" (",")" =>") ")
=> "foo (bar baz) bom"
>> "foo(bar baz) bom".gsub(/(?<=\S)\(|\)(?=\S)/,"(" =>" (",")" =>") ")
=> "foo (bar baz) bom"
>>
```

Comment: This adds additional whitespace around the parens if the string is like "foo (bar baz) bom". "foo (bar baz) bom" => "foo[two spaces](bar baz)[two spaces]bom"

Comment: Is there a gsub only way, which is not significantly more complicated?

Comment: @bjhaid Those are Hash(s), *key* is a match,*value* is substitution of the matched *key*.

Answer (score 0):

This is easier:

```
"foo(bar baz)bom".gsub(/(?<!\s)(?=\()|(?<=\))(?!\s)/, " ")
# => "foo (bar baz) bom"
```

Answer (score 0):

You were on the right track with `\S\)|\)\S`:

```
"foo(bar baz)bom".gsub /(?=\S\(|\)\S)(.)(.)/, '\1 \2'
#=> "foo (bar baz) bom"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't absolutely have to use gsub, you can do it this way. It's more verbose, but to me it's easier to read than long complex regular expressions:

```
s = "foo(bar baz)bom"
while s =~ /\w\(/
  s = $` + $&[0] + ' (' + $'
end
while s =~ /\)\w/
  s = $` + ') ' + $&[1] + $'
end
```

Like I say, it's verbose. But it's straightforward and there's no guesswork.

Of course you can replace

```
$` + $&[0] + ' (' + $'
```

with

```
"#{$`}#{$&[0]} (#{$'}"
```

if you prefer to use string interpolation rather than + or <<. But I think the first form is easier to read.

If you aren't familiar with this notation, $` is the part of the string before the match, $& is the matched string, and $' is the part after the match. It's easy to remember which is which because it's left to right on your keyboard.